# volatile переменная атомарная или нет?

Tags: java, jvm, volatile, атомарность

Почему операции над volatile переменными не атомарны?

upd: Переменная помеченная volatile является атомарной или нет?

Comment: Потому что volatile не делает операции переменной атомарными, поэтому они и не атомарны?

Comment: `volatile` это вообще не про атомарность.

Comment: ну вот ниже человек скинул противоположную точку зрения и предоставил документацию

Answer (score 2):

volatile обеспечивает только видимость (visibility) изменений, к атомарности он не имеет отношения. Классический пример со счетчиком: допустим есть поле volatile int i, к которому мы применим инкремент (декремент), возможна ситуация, когда два разных потока сначала проведут инкремент (декремент), а потом оба заберут результат двух инкрементов (декрементов). Такое воможно, потому что операции инкремента (декремента) не атомарны, а фактически состоят из последовательности операций, хотя и записываются одним выражением: i++ например.

Comment: Но ведь volatile обеспечивает атомарность считывание и записи double или long.

Comment: Хороший вопрос. Возможно, volatile не может обеспечить атомарность таких операций как инкремент потому, что это сложная составная операция (чтение + инкремент + запись). При записи long или double производится запись первых 32-х бит, затем вторых 32-х бит (запись + запись), в таких условиях атомарность соблюдается. Еще можно ответить, что согласно Java Language Specification параграф 17.7: Writes and reads of volatile long and double values are always atomic

Comment: `volatile` не обеспечивает никакой автомарности никому. `volatile` только означает, что значение не будет кешироваться потоком.

Comment: @tym32167 `volatile` обеспечивает атомарность чтения и записи переменной
 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html

Comment: @IR42 `This means that changes to a volatile variable are always visible to other threads` то есть атомарность в данном случае это следствие того, что значение не кешируется потоком. Другими словами, атомарность для не-volatile переменных рушится из за наличия кеша потока, который отключен для volatile переменных. Это не назначение ключевого слова,  а его побочный эффект. Назначение же volatile это иметь консистентность значения среди потоков, то есть если вы записали в переменную число 10, то уверены, что все потоки, которые прочитают эту переменную, прочитают именно число 10.

Answer (score 0):

**Кратко:**

Мой вопрос оказался некорректным. Переменная помеченная ключевым словом `volatile` является **атомарной** **для чтения и записи**.
**Операции** над переменной помеченной  `volatile` **НЕ** являются **атомарными**

**Подробно:**

**Атомарная операция** выглядит единой и неделимой командой процессора, которая может быть или уже выполненной или ещё невыполненной.

Если переменную сделать `volatile`, то **запись** и **чтение** происходит ***атомарно***. НО если, происходит какая-то операция, например, `инкримент`, то уже ***атомарность*** не обеспечивается, потому что это сначала выполняется **чтение(1)**, потом **изменение(2)** в локальной памяти, а затем **запись(3)**. Такая операция не является атомарной и в неё может вклиниться поток по середине.

Источник: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html